# Sequelize: Fetching with include returns not associated error

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following tables:

1. User
2. Event
3. RSVPs

`User` has 1:M relationship with `Event`
`User` has 1:M relationship with `RSVPs`

`Event` has 1:M relationship with `RSVPs`

When fetching `Event`s, I would like to include `RSVPs` and for `RSVPs` I would like to include `User`.

Associations:

**User**

```
        tableName: 'Users',
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {

                User.hasMany(models.Event, {
                    as: 'events',
                    foreignKey: 'user_id'
                })

                 User.hasMany(models.RSVPs, {
                     as: 'rsvps',
                     foreignKey: 'user_id'                         
                 })

            }
        },
```

**Event**

```
        tableName: 'Events',
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {
                Event.belongsTo(models.User, {
                    foreignKey: {
                        name: 'owner_id',
                        allowedNull: false,

                    }
                }),
                Event.belongsTo(models.User, {
                    foreignKey: {
                        name: 'host_id',
                        allowedNull: true,

                    }
                }),
                Event.hasMany(models.RSVPs, {
                    as: 'rsvps',
                    foreignKey: 'event_id'
                })
            }
        }
```

**RSVP**

```
        tableName: 'RSVPs',
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {
                Rsvp.belongsTo(models.User, {
                    foreignKey: {
                        name: 'user_id',
                        allowedNull: false,
                    }                    }),

                    Rsvp.belongsTo(models.Event, {
                        foreignKey: {
                            name: 'event_id',
                            allowedNull: false,
                        }
                    })
            }
        },
```

Attempting to fetch:

```
db.Event.findAll({
            where: {
                id: eventIds
            },
            order: [['updatedAt', 'ASC']],
            limit: pagingLimit + 1, 
            include: [{
                model: db.RSVPs,
                as: 'rsvps',
                include: [{
                    model: db.User,
                    as: 'user_id',
                    include: [{
                        model: db.AppCommon,
                        as: 'app_common'
                    }],
                }]
            }, {
                model: db.tasks,
                as: 'tasks',
            }]
        }).then(events => {
            //Do Something
        }
```

I didn't include association code from `Tasks` and `AppCommon` b/c I didn't think they are relevant.  I can update the question, if needed.

**Problem:**

When I fetch `Event` with `.findAll` code above, I get the following message:

```
Express listening on port 3000!
Unhandled rejection Error: User (user_id) is not associated to RSVPs!
```

I am hoping to fetch `Event` that returns a `Task` and `RSVP`object -- within that `RSVP` object there is a `User` object, and within that `User` Object there is a `AppCommon` object.  What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I tried to simplify the query to:

```
db.RSVPs.findAll({
    where: {
        user_id: req.user_id
    },
    include: [{
        model: db.User,
        as: 'user'
    }]
}).then(rsvps => {

)}
```

Associations:

```
       tableName: 'RSVPs',
        classMethods: {
            associate: function (models) {

                Rsvp.belongsTo(models.Event, {
                    foreignKey: {
                        name: 'event_id',
                        allowedNull: false,
                    }
                }),

                    Rsvp.belongsTo(models.User, {
                        foreignKey: 'user_id'
                    })

                }
        },
```

But this is failing with "`Error: User (user) is not associated to RSVPs!`"

Comment: did you try removing those `as` in your query? Might be conflicting with the foreignKey (?)

Comment: Yes, then I get `Unhandled rejection Error: RSVPs is not associated to Event!` error.

Comment: Did you try to simplify that query? Try to fetch Event and include only Rsvp

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I did.  When I remove the second `include`, it appears to work.  When included, i get the following error: `Unhandled rejection Error: User (users) is not associated to RSVPs!`

Comment: Try to find all Rsvp and include users. (without event)

Comment: I can find Rsvp with `where: {
            user_id: req.user_id
        },`  However, it fails when I include:     `db.RSVPs.findAll({
        where: {
            user_id: req.user_id
        },
        include: [{
            model: db.User,
            as: 'user'
        }]
    }).`   
The error is: `User (user) is not associated to RSVPs!`

Comment: BTW, `RSVPs` can only have 1 `User`  not `users`.   `User` has 1:M relationship with `RSVPs`.  I need to get the `User` object along with `RSVPs`

Comment: Change your RSVP association to this: `Rsvp.belongsTo(models.User, {foreignKey: 'user_id' })`. Something in that association definition is messed up.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried the associate above but no avail.  Even deleted and recreated the RSVPs table again.  Does my second `include` look okay?

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: Looks alright. You will have to completely isolate everything. Create a new js file, define the models there and debug until you find what's wrong. It's probably some damn simple

Comment: I got it!  You are right -- under `    include: [{
        model: db.User,
        as: 'user'
    }]`     `user` needed to be `User`   Thank you for your help.  If you want to create an answer, I can mark it as correct?